# Simple Logic gates with circuitikz - increase I/O line length

Tags: circuitikz

I need some help with the increasing the length of the input and output lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{logic ports origin=center}
    \draw (0,0) node[and port, scale=2] (myand) {}
    (myand.in 1) node[anchor=east] {1}
    (myand.in 2) node[anchor=east] {2}
    (myand.out) node[anchor=west] {3};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`american` ports do not have an option to change lead pin lengths (although they can be suppressed, see the manual around page 117). So you have to extend them manually ... and optionally add coordinate names for later use:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{logic ports origin=center}
    \draw (0,0) node[and port, scale=2] (myand) {}
    (myand.in 1) -- ++(-1,0) coordinate(myand-in1) node[anchor=east]{1}
    (myand.in 2)-- ++(-1,0) coordinate(myand-in2)  node[anchor=east]{2}
    (myand.out) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(myand-out) node[anchor=west]{3};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `ieee logic ports` does have an option for the lead length (manual page 124):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{logic ports=ieee, ieeestd ports/pin length=2}
    \draw (0,0) node[and port, scale=2] (myand) {}
    (myand.in 1) node[anchor=east]{1}
    (myand.in 2) node[anchor=east]{2}
    (myand.out) node[anchor=west]{3};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great - thank you so much!

Comment: @lex2763 https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers